# How to convert IST time to UTC time in C(Ubuntu)?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, timezone

I am working on GPS project, for that I want to add Time-Stamps(UTC) after each receiving gps data. How can I convert IST to UTC in C ? I subtract 5:30 hours to tv.tv_sec, but this not the correct way. Is there any function to get UTC from IST ?

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE          50     /* for TimeStampsForServer */
int fnTimeStampsForGpsData ()
{
        struct timeval tv;
        struct tm *ptm;

        char TimeString[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

        long MicroSeconds;

        /**
         *  Obtain the time of day, and convert it to a tm struct.
         */
        gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
        tv.tv_sec -= 19800;         /* Number of seconds (5:30) */
        ptm = localtime (&tv.tv_sec);

        /**
         * Format the date and time, down to a single second.
         */
        strftime (TimeString, sizeof (TimeString), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ptm);

        /**
         *  Copying  microseconds.
         */
        MicroSeconds = tv.tv_usec;

        /**
         *  Print the formatted time, in seconds, followed by a decimal point
         *   and the microseconds.
         */
        printf ("%s.%06ld\n", TimeString, MicroSeconds);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the `tzset()` manpage. It documents a global variable `timezone` which resembles the timezone offset of your local time (according to your system settings) to GMT once `tzset()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the timestamp into broken down fields in UTC instead of whatever timezone you as an user are currently using, stop using `localtime()`, and use [`gmtime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gmtime.3.html) instead!

You see, `time_t` timestamps are always in UTC. [`gettimeofday()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), and [`time()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) all provide timestamps in UTC. The type description itself says it describes the number of seconds since Epoch in UTC.

To break timestamps down into separate fields, you use [`gmtime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gmtime.3.html) if you want the parts in UTC, or `localtime()` if you want the current timezone to be used instead.

You clearly use `localtime()` in your example. That is the source of your problem. Because you (you as in the logged in user on your machine) have configured the Indian timezone -- it's user-specific, not machine-specific --, `localtime()` dutifully breaks the time down, *using Indian Standard Time rules*.

---

Kolkata is the most populous Indian city listed in the timezone database, so in a C program, you can use

```
setenv("TZ", ":Asia/Kolkata", 1);
tzset();
```

and [`localtime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) and other time functions that work on local time will use the Indian timezone.

You can see how this works using just the command line, too:

```
date
TZ=:Asia/Kolkata date
date -u
TZ=:Asia/Kolkata date -u
```

The `-u` flag tells `date` to output the date using UTC, instead of local time. (Same as using `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()`.)

Since the setting is process-wide, it's a bit more complicated to do in a multithreaded process or a service process. A service process (daemon) could use a slave process to do the conversions, communicating with the arent using a socket pair (and exiting when the socket closes, thus exiting whenever the parent exits). Alternatively, mutually exclusive locks (say, `pthread_mutex_t` mutex) could be used to protect the local-time functions, so that at most one thread is relying on the functionality at any given time. (UTC time functionality is not affected, so the performance loss might be acceptable, as it'd only affect the local-time functions.)